# DATEFORMAT accepts only YYYY-MM-DD not DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to store data in a table with SQL Server, but the problem is when inserting data it accepts YYYY-MM-DD but not DD-MM-YYYY, the column is type date

The code is

```
INSERT INTO datetime2022 (ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ)
VALUES ('26-12-2022');
```

And the error message is:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But with the code:

```
INSERT INTO datetime2022 (ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ)
VALUES ('2022-12-30')
```

All is ok, need the table to accept date in ddmmyyyy format

Comment: Dates are not strings thus the table does not "accept" a string value, it accepts a date value.  You need to format your strings in such a way that they correctly convert to a format SQL Server recognizes as a proper date.  There are a myriad of other questions on this site that cover this.

Comment: sql server convert string to date only when they conform with their wanted formats 20221230 would also work

Comment: Documentation for MySQL isnt very relevant for SQL Server @fredrik .

Comment: Missed that. Here's the relevant doc for mssql https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @johncanyon What we're saying is that SQL Server doesn't store dates in any format at all.  Thus the "table does not 'accept'" one format over the other.  You have to be specific on how you format a string as a representation of a date in order for SQL Server to accept it and store the value you're expecting.  If you enter the date using a ddmmyyyy format, that's where it ends.  When you query the value you'll still need to apply formatting to it to display it in ddmmyyyy format, whether in the query or in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DateFormat DMY`

**Example**

```
Set DateFormat DMY

Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeDT] datetime) 
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
('26-12-2022')
 
Select * From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeDT
2022-12-26 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Set DateFormat DMY itworks accept the date but still store it yyyy-mm-dd, it's better than nothing i guess thank you

Comment: It's not "stored" in a format at all, @johncanyon , it's stored as a binary value. The format the value is **displayed** in is a job for your presentation layer.

Comment: @johncanyon This is just to get your data into your table without throwing an exception.   Dates do not have a format... that belongs in the presentation layer.